# How to call a keyDown method with Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    //
}

- (IBAction)entrer:(NSTextField *)sender {
    [super keyDown];

    }
}



@end
```

I want to call the keyDown method above but I have an error 
No visible interface for NSObject declares the selector 'keyDown'
How to call my void keyDown method from the entrer method ?

Comment: No visible interface for NSObject declares the selector 'keyDown' , also

Comment: cmd-click on the symbol and you will see that  `keyDown:` is a method of class `NSResponder`. For example `NSWindow` and `NSView` respond to that method because they are subclasses of `NSResponder`. NSObject does not.

Answer (score 1):

The `-keyDown:` method takes a parameter. Therefore, it's name is `-keyDown:` **with a colon**. The colon is a required part of the name and the parameter is a required part of calling the method.

You could call it using:

```
[self keyDown:nil];
```

but you would have to be sure that your `-keyDown:` method can handle a `nil` parameter.

Alternatively, you could obtain or construct an instance of `NSEvent` and pass that. Exactly how to do that depends on what you're trying to accomplish by calling `-keyDown:`.

Which brings us to the fact that it's odd to want to call `-keyDown:`. That method is normally called by the framework to ask an object to handle a key-down event. You would not typically call it yourself. That's part of why it's non-obvious where to get the `NSEvent` to pass to it, because you're calling it outside of the normal event-handling mechanism.

Comment: Ken has a very good point.  It makes more sense to me to add a `handleKeyDown` method which is called by the `keyDown` method and can be called elsewhere in your code, than to call `keyDown` itself.